# Como detectar a versao do sistema operacional Windows?

Tags: c#, sistema-operacional

Quero obter um valor de qual sistema está utilizando, como:

- Windows 7 ou
- Windows 8 ou
- Windows 8.1 ou
- Windows 10

Como eu posso fazer isso em C# ? Já tentei `System.Environment.OSVersion` não funciona direito.

Tentei essa resposta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2819974/6647038) e não funciona. Estou usando **Windows10**, ele retorna como **Windows8**.

Já tentei no stackoverflow "Inglês", nenhuma delas não funcionou com esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819934/detect-windows-version-in-net).

Comment: Você leu a nota da resposta aceita no SOen? Ela parece explicar poque detecta como windows 8 mesmo executando o 10.

Comment: ***Important note**: if your executable assembly manifest doesn't explicitly state that your exe assembly is compatible with Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.0, System.Environment.OSVersion will return Windows 8.0 version ?! which is 6.2, instead of 6.3 and 10.0!! Source: here first comment.**

Comment: De qualquer forma, deixo outra alternativa: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885836/5524514

Comment: @Articuno o link que você mandou funciona, caso alguém mudar o valor no registro, ferro.

Comment: Se alguem mudar essa chave ai, vai fechar muito mais do que sua aplicacao :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu utilizo o `ManagementObjectSearcher` do namespace `System.Management`

Exemplo:

```
string r = "";
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"))
{
    ManagementObjectCollection information = searcher.Get();
    if (information != null)
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject obj in information)
        {
            r = obj["Caption"].ToString() + " - " + obj["OSArchitecture"].ToString();
        }
    }
    r = r.Replace("NT 5.1.2600", "XP");
    r = r.Replace("NT 5.2.3790", "Server 2003");
    MessageBox.Show(r);
}
```

> Não esqueça de adicionar a referência para o Assembly `System.Management.dll`
>   e colocar o using: `using System.Management;`

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ps. O meu é Windows 8.1 mesmo =]

[**Documentação**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Rovan, responda isso tbm no stackoverflow "ingles" kkkkkkk, funciona mesmo.

Comment: fui olhar lá tambem, já estava como respondida... mas posso colocar lá sim =]... e olha que uso isso há um bom tempo...e da mesma forma, pego informação sobre processador, placa mae, e memória

Comment: Só uma dúvida, porque isso: `r = r.Replace("NT 5.1.2600", "XP"); r = r.Replace("NT 5.2.3790", "Server 2003");` ?

Comment: quando é windows xp, ou server 2003, o retorno é `Microsoft Windows NT 5.1.2600`, coloco o replace pra retornar: `Microsoft Windows XP`